# What is the simplest way to batch crop differently sized photos?

Tags: photoshop, batch, cropping, action

I'm new here. I would really appreciate your help. Let's say I have a few hundred photos of a model on infinite background, shot from four different angles: front, back, side and full length. Is there any way to batch crop them so that in every photo the model is in the center?

I've already tried using Photoshop batch crop, but it doesn't help since not all photos were shot from the same exact distance.. I think I will have to use some script that can detect the model.. Thanks in advance. Any ideas or advices would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

About a year ago, I used [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) wrapped in a Python script and using the Linux [convert](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm) tool to detect the faces and scale/transform the image so that the the faces line up and are (more or less) on the same scale.

I leaned heavily on this [example/blog](https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/).  I hope this helps you too. If you really want, I can post my code if you're interested.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action to resize your photos to a template, Suppose  you have a template 1500 X 1000 and you can place all your images in to that template and resize it  by percentage.Let’s say 40% of the 1500 X 1000 document. Even though you will have to do some adjustments manually as the photos are not shot from same distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to stack the photographs, It would then place every image on it's own layer - crop it as a document and then save each layer as an image (via an action).

File > Scripts > Load files into stack

Only cons to this would be file size if you have 100's.

Hope this helps